# Adding non-entity fields to a form

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, field

How can I add a non-entity field to a Symfony 1.4 form ? For example: a checkbox in a movie adding form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as any other widget to the form's `widgetSchema`. Of course you have to remember to also add a validator or the validation will fail with an `unexpected field` error.

Symfony is smart enough to ignore the field when persisting the object to the database.

Comment: didnt work for me if you use only the widget. you have to use both widget and validator to have access to the field on the post validator. thanks